# Problems with div not assuming total height

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/wgWAx/4/

The JQuery alert should report the #parentDiv height, and, as you can see, its original height is 2000+ and not 532 as is displays.

This happens because its height is set to 100%, but how can I make this 100% mark the page height, or should I say, the original #parentDiv's height?

The #childDiv, should maintain its height, being the whole body height.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <header id="childDiv">
        <div id="anotherDiv"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="spaceDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle works when you get rid of

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I remove that part of the CSS, the #childDiv loses it's height value, that should be the whole screen height.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? If that was a requirement, you should clarify your question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

remove the height:100% from 
html, body

Right now the body get's 100% of your view (try resizeing the window and refresh)

Comment: Yes, but if I remove that part of the CSS, the #childDiv loses it's height value, that should be the whole screen height.

Comment: No, the #childDiv has not the height of the body and It should